# HTML Purifier: allow user styling

Tags: html, css

Our software recently got hit by XSS attacks through a feature that allows users to style their own posts using HTML and CSS.
Is it possible to allow user styling of their own forum posts while sanitising anything else?

This is the code we have so far:

```
require_once 'module/purifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();

$config->set('Core.Encoding', 'ISO-8859-1');
$config->set('HTML.Doctype', 'HTML 4.01 Transitional');
$config->set('CSS.Trusted', true);
$config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'style,div[id|class]');

$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
...
echo $purifier->purify($uheader); // $uheader contains the CSS code wrapped between "style" tags and a "div" class.
```

However, while testing I still can't see my custom style applied.

**UPDATE 1**

As per request, the HTML code:

```
<img src="test"onerror="alert('XSS TEST')">
<style>
CSS_CODE_HERE
</style>
<div class="mainbar1-1">
```

I added that "img src" tag just to make sure that one gets filtered properly.

Comment: can you provide the html for which its not working

Comment: I can if you don't mind it to be really long. :P

Comment: Nope just asking the particular tags for which its failing

Comment: Added the HTML code.

Comment: Do you use HTML Purifier? http://htmlpurifier.org/

Comment: Yes, that's why I put it in both the title and the body of the question.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 3 :**  Use the below settings

```
$config->set('HTML.AllowedAttributes', '*.style');
```

Comment: No luck with this one, the style tags are still being filtered out.

Comment: Sorry , use my settings without  ---> $config->set('HTML.AllowedAttributes', array('*.style' => true)); See my edits

Comment: With that line out of the way, "style" still gets filtered out.
But at least "div class" is not.

Comment: So basically you want your style tag and div with class to be ignored by htmlpurifier rioght ??

Comment: Yes, both these tags should be allowed while disallowing any other tags.

Comment: @Annonymousisnobody check now

Comment: No, still no luck. I'm literally talking about the "style" tags themselves, by the way.